# (Macro Creation) Syntax Error in C

Tags: c, syntax, macros

I've already created the macros for the assignment, but cannot find the syntax error I get when running the program. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ODD(X) ((X) & 01)
#define BITON(X,N) (((X) >> N) & 01)
#define ALLON(X,S,E) (((X) & ((((int) pow(2,(E-S))-1) << (E-S))) ^ (((int) pow(2,E-S)-1) << (E-S)))
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                          
int main(void) {

  unsigned int U1,BitNumber,Start,End;

  printf("Enter an integer : ");
  scanf("%ud",&U1);
  printf("%u is %s\n",U1,ODD(U1)?"odd":"even");

  printf("Enter an integer and a bit number : ");
  scanf("%u %d",&U1,&BitNumber);
  printf("%u has bit %d %s\n",U1,BitNumber,BITON(U1,BitNumber)?"on":"off");

  printf("Enter an integer, start and end bit numbers : ");
  scanf("%u %u %u",&U1,&Start,&End);
  printf("%u has %s those bits on\n",U1,ALLON(U1,Start,End)?"all":"not all");

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Error:

```
BitOps.c: In function ‘main’:
BitOps.c:23:77: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
   printf("%u has %s those bits on\n",U1,ALLON(U1,Start,End)?"all":"not all");
                                                                             ^
BitOps.c:26:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
 }
```

Comment: The compiler does not tell you the line number of the syntax error? Strange.

Comment: `#define BITON(X,N) (((X) >> N) & 01)` Wouldn't `((X) & (1 << (N)))` be better?

Comment: @bipll Depends on whether 0/1 is desired as result.

Comment: I copied the actual body of the program from the assignment itself, the only additions to the code should have been under the #define lines; that's why it's strange to see syntax errors.

Comment: Yes, sure. Converting a true value to 1 is the second operation anyway.

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis in ALLON. but you should really read up on why pow is not needed for your assignment

Answer (score 1):

The macro definition of `ALLON`  has an extra open parenthesis in it.  The compiler can't be sure that it's wrong until it reaches the semicolon at the end of the line where `ALLON` is used, so the error message complains about that line (which is fine) rather than the definition of `ALLON`, but the definition of `ALLON` is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `-Wall` flags and compile the code, its very informative, don't ignore it. There are few bugs in your code as

- Better `01` replace with `0x1` that serve actual purpose.
- Read the warning, `BitNumber` is declared as `unsigned` but `%d` format specifier is used. Compile your code with `-Wall` flag.
- `ALLON()` macro expansion is not correct, which I correctly added below.

Here is expected one

```
#define ODD(X) ((X) & 0x1)
#define BITON(X,N) (((X) >> N) & 0x1)
#define ALLON(X,S,E) (((X) & ( ((((int) pow(2,(E-S))-1) << (E-S))) ^ (((int) pow(2,E-S)-1) << (E-S)))) )

int main(void) {

  unsigned int U1,BitNumber,Start,End;

  printf("Enter an integer : ");
  scanf("%u",&U1);
  printf("%u is %s\n",U1,ODD(U1)?"odd":"even");

  printf("Enter an integer and a bit number : ");
  scanf("%u %u",&U1,&BitNumber);
  printf("%u has bit %d %s\n",U1,BitNumber,BITON(U1,BitNumber)?"on":"off");

  printf("Enter an integer, start and end bit numbers : ");
  scanf("%u %u %u",&U1,&Start,&End);
  printf("%u has %s those bits on\n",U1,ALLON(U1,Start,End) ?"all":"not all");

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, achal for your response. I'm now getting another error after changing my code per your suggestions:                       
/tmp/ccrRqgmy.o: In function `main':
BitOps.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `pow'
BitOps.c:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: link with `-lm`. for e.g `gcc -Wall  test.c  -lm`

Comment: why are you even using `pow` ?   that's strange

Comment: I think your assignment is also trying to figure out if you know how to *remove* the use of *`pow`* and understand what bit-shifting actually means.

Comment: Agree @AhmedMasud `pow()` is un-necessary here. OP should learn more of bit shifting.